# How can I make a NestJS GraphQL request bypass the built-in exception filter and only use the global exception filter for error handling?

Tags: nestjs-graphql

I'm currently working with NestJS and GraphQL, and I'm trying to handle all errors using a custom global exception filter that I've created. However, I've noticed that the built-in exception filter always handles and logs the errors before my custom filter gets a chance to do so.

I find this behavior quite puzzling, especially when dealing with errors that occur during a GraphQL request. I've tested this with a simple HTTP request and found that the global exception filter handles all errors as expected, without triggering the built-in exception filter.

So, my question is: How can I configure my application to only trigger my custom global filter and bypass the built-in exception filter when handling errors?

Here's a snippet of my code for reference:

foo-resolver.ts
FooResolver:

```js
import { Query, Resolver } from "@nestjs/graphql";
import { ApolloError } from "apollo-server-express";

@Resolver()
export class FooResolver {
  @Query(() => String)
  error(): string {
    throw new ApolloError('throw Error');
    return 'Hello World!';
  }
}
```

global-exception.filter.ts:

```js
import { ArgumentsHost, Catch, Logger } from "@nestjs/common";
import { GqlArgumentsHost, GqlContextType, GqlExceptionFilter } from "@nestjs/graphql";

@Catch()
export class GlobalExceptionFilter implements GqlExceptionFilter {
  private logger = new Logger(this.constructor.name);

  catch(exception: any, host: ArgumentsHost): void {
    if (host.getType() === 'http') {
      // do something that is only important in the context of regular HTTP requests (REST)
      const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    } else if (host.getType<GqlContextType>() === 'graphql') {
      const gqlHost = GqlArgumentsHost.create(host);
    }
  }
}
```

main.ts

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalFilters(new GlobalExceptionFilter());
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

I hope this makes my question clear. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I tried to handle all errors in my NestJS application using a custom global exception filter. I expected that all errors, including those from GraphQL requests, would be handled by this filter. However, I found that the built-in exception filter is still handling and logging the errors before my custom filter gets a chance to do so.